# Android - Is it possible to iteratively generate random numbers while toggle button is on?

Tags: java, android, random, toggle

I am trying to create an app in Android that generates number repetitively while the toggle button is on. So, when the user taps the toggle again to turn it off it will stop generating random numbers. But I am not sure if it is possible, because my code keeps on getting a run-time error because of infinite loop. 
Is it possible to iteratively generate random numbers while toggle button is on?

MainActivity.java

```
package dan.cielos;

import android.widget.CompoundButton;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar; 
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.MultiAutoCompleteTextView;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.ToggleButton;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.NumberPicker;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//private
private int min = 1;
private int max = 100;
private TextView txt;

/*public boolean recurse(boolean toggle) {
    if (toggle == false) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return recurse(toggle);
    }
}*/

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_random);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numPick);
    final TextView rn = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.random_number);
    final ToggleButton tog = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.random_button);
    np.setMinValue(min);
    np.setMaxValue(max);
    toolbar.setTitle("Random Number");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    tog.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v){
                //recurse(tog.isChecked());
                if (tog.isChecked()) {//the result i want to achieve is while the toggle button is on, iteratively generate numbers until user press the toggle button again

                    double ran = Math.random() * (max -min) + min;
                    ran = Math.round(ran);
                    rn.setText(Double.toString(Math.floor(ran)));

                }

            }
        });
    }


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


}
```

activity_random.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="dan.cielos.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

 </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Number"
    android:id="@+id/random_number"
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/random_button"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ToggleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New ToggleButton"
    android:id="@+id/random_button"
    android:height="75dp"
    android:width="150dp"
    android:textOff="Generate"
    android:textOn="Stop"
    android:layout_marginBottom="58dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<NumberPicker
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/numPick"
    android:layout_above="@id/random_number"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: I don't know the purpose and your code but i believe you are doing infinite loop in UI thread thats why you are getting error. Try using AsyncTask or IntentService to do this in background

Comment: Why not? You can use a flag (true while toggle is on) to call the function again inside the function (recursive). Please try and write when you encounter a problem. Add the code piece.

Comment: are you reading those random numbers?
maybe it's better to use a handler and run every X milliseconds

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop is bad, because you don't want the program to halt while you're generating the numbers. Remember - Android needs to run its UI so that the changes you made can be displayed properly.

Instead, you want to show a different random number every short time interval (lets say every 100 ms?) so long as the toggle button is clicked.

Here's how you could achieve this:

```
private boolean isGeneratingRandomNum; // <-- this will prevent duplicate initiations of the "loop"
private boolean isToggleButtonOn; // <-- change this value to true / false depending on whether or not the button is on.

private void displayRandomNumber() {
    // if the toggle button is off, stop
    // if the loop iteration has already started, stop
    if (!isToggleButtonOn || isGeneratingRandomNum)
        return;

    // indicate that the loop iteration has begun
    isGeneratingRandomNum = true;

    // your code for setting a random number
    double ran = Math.random() * (max -min) + min;
    ran = Math.round(ran);
    rn.setText(Double.toString(Math.floor(ran)));

   // set up the next iteration to occur in 100 ms on the ui thread.
   postDelayed(new Runnable() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           // indicate that the loop iteration is done, meaning we are ready to perform another iteration.
           isGeneratingRandomNum = false;

           // call the method again.
           displayRandomNumber();
       }
   }, 100);
}

// call this method from your toggleButton onClickListener
private void onToggleButtonChange() {
    isToggleButtonOn = !isToggleButtonOn;

    if (isToggleButtonOn)
       displayRandomNumber();
}
```